# Different browsers allow different amounts of emoji characters in a maxlength field

Tags: javascript, html, emoji

I'm trying to make an html input field that matches the database limit of 100 characters. I have a utf8mb4 database to support emoji, however the problem is the browser and database all count the length of emoji differently.

The  emoji is the codepoint U+{1F600}.

- The db will count this codepoint `U+{1F600}` as 1 entry. So I could fit 100 in a db entry.
- maxlength in Safari computes the single codepoint, "" == 1. So I could enter the expected 100.
- maxlength in Chrome counts the surrogate pair `U+D83D, U+DE00` since the original codepoint is greater than 2 bytes, "" == 2. So I could only enter 50 in my form.

Given that different browsers treat emoji with different lengths with respect to a form's maxlength attribute, what would be the cleanest way to accept a max of 100  emojis in a form across browsers?

Comment: `"".length` gives `2` in my Safari too, so manual checking might do. I don't know how they messed up their `maxlength` attribute though...

Comment: That is javascript (utf-16) so it will take any emoji characters that are greater than 2 bytes and use a surrogate pair, resulting in 2 codepoints. I'm finding that the input maxlength attribute is what differs between browsers.

Comment: Yes, but according to [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-maxlength-and-minlength-attributes), they should use the *code-unit length* to determine the validity of this attribute. Safari is faulty here. So the cleanest would be that all browsers follow the specs, but that's a sweet dream, so the less clean way is to check this by yourself...